# Manipulate HTML5 application history

Tags: javascript, cordova, browser-history

I have the following scenario for a `PhoneGap` mobile app:

1. App opens and displays index.html
2. User logs in and gets redirected to home.html
3. User can then go to news.html
4. I want to handle the back button in the home.html in a way that if the previous page (the one after you go back in history) was news.html, I want to browser to go back in history using `navigator.app.backHistory();`. But if the previous page is the index.html, I want to close the app using `navigator.app.exitApp();`

My point is, after logging in, the user should never be able to land on index.html again.

Comment: This seems like misguided usability - the entire purpose of the history is to be able to reach pages you previously visited, you're doing something wrong if you're scripting to defy that. What about your app is requiring this behavior?

Comment: What kind of server-side scripting are you using? Maybe you can have have your index.php either serve a login page or a home page depending on a session state?

Comment: it's an HTML page, no server side code.
But you don't want the user to be shown the login page after he logs in

Comment: Agreed, but there are better ways than overwriting native browser behavior. Check out cookies - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp. If you don't detect a cookie, the user isn't logged in, therefore display the login page. If you do detect a cookie, the user is logged in, therefore display the home content.

Comment: how can cookies or localStorage fix that? The user is till going to pass by the index.html page to open the home.html page. The problem is when he presses back

Comment: [facepalm] The point is to have your homepage on index.html, so that when the user hits back they are taken back to the homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this, do the following:

1. App opens and displays index.html
2. User logs in and <s>gets redirected to home.html</s> using History API you replace the current state of the page with "home.html" by using `history.replaceState()`
3. Now the user "never was" on index.html in the first place

Read about [manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). This should work with Phonegap.

Comment: replaceState was what I was looking for! it works, this is the code:
`history.replaceState({page: this.href}, '', 'home.html');`  
`document.location = 'home.html';`